# Change length of name fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise. When you create a custom entity, you get a default "name" field which is a string with 100 characters. You can change that datatype during entity creation but we didn't do that.

Now we learned that 100 chars are not enough in our usecase, we would need 120 or 150. 
The solution designer allows changing the string length but when we save the changes we get a generic database error.

Question: Is there a known workaround to change the string length of the main field?

Obviously, it is possible to create a new entity and copy the data from the old to the new entity. Since we have many views, forms and references between entities, this is not really feasible.

Comment: What you're doing sounds like it should work. What security role(s) does the user have that's making the update? Have you tried updating other fields?  Also, it is interesting to note that last year others were reporting similar issues: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/167733

Comment: Could you please turn on the trace (https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/907490/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm) and edit the answer with the error?

Comment: @Aron: The user is system admin, so it shouldn't be a permission thing. We are updating other fields all the time, so that's fine.

Comment: @FedericoJousset: While I am system admin I do not have access to the server. To turn on trace (which is probably the sensible next thing to do) I need a server admin and that is always a major hassle. If nobody can say for sure whether this should work or not, I probably need to take that path.

Comment: The length of the name field can be changed without a problem. Generic database errors usually have a technical cause, e.g. full transaction log, full disk etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using any conventional solutions (i.e. through the UI) due to constraints in the Database. The default name field is the primary key of the table. I encourage you to remake the entity and migrate existing data to the new entity.

If this is really not feasible then you can try to change the length of the column directly in the SQL DB, but that is unsupported so it might break the environment. If you want to try this be sure that you test this in an disposable environment.
I have never done it so I don't know the outcome but that is something that I would try.